# How can I load fonts from a different location in MathJax?

Tags: javascript, fonts, mathjax

MathJax enforces a directory structure based on its library design. Fonts bundled with the library are in a subdirectory alongside some Javascript configuration and other components.

I want to serve the fonts from a different location on disk but I'm not seeing any configuration values that allow me to do that. I've checked the [documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/index.html) and while I'm seeing different ways to load the full library and pieces of configuration, I'm not seeing how to isolate the fonts.

How can I load fonts from a different location in MathJax?

Edit: This is a client-side solution; we're doing this in the browser. We're using the `TeX-AMS_CHTML.js` configuration, which uses the CommonHTML rendering strategy. In the configuration (which is minified) it looks like there's a `MathJax.OutputJax.fontDir` that could be edited?

Comment: You might want to share more details about your setup, e.g., client vs server side, which output etc. For the HTML-CSS and SVG output (which does not use fonts but JS files), this is not really possible. For the CommonHTML output, simply overwriting the font-face declarations in your CSS should work.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I've edited the question to include the configuration options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to override the CommonHTML `webfontDir`.  Try

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook('CommonHTML Jax Ready", function () {
  MathJax.OutputJax.CommonHTML.webfontDir = 'myURL/myDontDirectory';
});
</script>
```

where `myURL/myFontDirectory` is the full URL to the directory containing your fonts.  You may need to set the access control for the fonts directory to allow cross-domain access if the URL domain is not the same as the domain of the page loading MathJax.  See the MathJax documentation on [shared installations](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/installation.html#cross-domain-linking) for more details.

Comment: This, unfortunately, doesn't seem to be working. The callback function is running, but the fonts still aren't loading from the location I've specified. The documentation, unfortunately, talks about hosting cross-domain issues with older browsers I don't have to support, but doesn't share much more information. Is there a listing of the registration hooks anywhere? Perhaps I need to change the font location earlier in the pipeline?

Comment: Also, note that we're loading from the same domain, just a different directory path that we use for all assets and resources (like fonts).

Comment: Can you post an example?  It is hard to diagnose without seeing what you are actually doing.

Comment: I got this working by using the "End Config" event instead of "CommonHTML Jax Ready". It seemed to be a pipeline issue.

Comment: Sorry, you are right "CommonHTML Jax Ready" is too late (the font data file will already be loaded and the web font directory used.  The proper signal is probably "CommonHTML Jax Config", but if "End Config" works for you, that's fine.

Answer (score 2):

From v3 onwards, use the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.MathJax = {
  startup: {
    ready: () => {
      MathJax.config.chtml.fontURL = "/your-path/es5/output/chtml/fonts/woff-v2";
      MathJax.config.chtml.font.options.fontURL = "/your-path/es5/output/chtml/fonts/woff-v2";
      MathJax.startup.defaultReady();
    }
  }
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/your-path/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
```